# How to get google hangout button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I tried to get access to iframe content from google hangout button but I ran into cross domain error.

All I want to do is make my own button and when user clicks on it, then google hangout button's click event is fired.

I want to know if it is even possible to make my own button rather than google hangout button...

I have tried many ways to access iframe content but I could not find any solution.

Comment: Could you please show us what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for this problem
it seems accessing to **`iframe`** events is impossible and that's why the owner use **`iframe`** to protect the code from being manipulated...

Answer (score 0):

I had no Idea But can you try to change the Image URL and see what happens.Button must contain the app ID of your Hangout app or extension You have Replace APP_ID with GOTO [https://code.google.com/apis/console/] and create APPID here of your Hangout and see If It Possible after changing the URL

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID" style="text-decoration:none;">
<img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/hangout/1/gplus-hangout-15x79-normal.png"
alt="Start a Hangout"
style="border:0;width:79px;height:15px;"/>
</a>
```